# How to change pitch value according to plane propeller speed change?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This script is attached to the plane propeller and the propeller start spinning smooth slowly to max speed.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spin : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float RotationSpeed = 1;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, 0, RotationSpeed, Space.Self);

        if (RotationSpeed < 10)
        {
            RotationSpeed += 1f * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```

I added empty gameobject with audio source component and a script that control the pitch of the audio source component.

[image: pitch control]

what i want to do is to sync between the pitch value changes and the plane propeller speed changes.

now the plane propeller start spinning when i'm running the game and i want to use the pitch to make the sound like starting the plane engine from slowly to fast.

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion:**

I believe you are looking for:

```cs
public class AudioPitchManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public int startingPitch = 4;
    public int decreaseAmount = 5;
    private AudioSource _audioSource;

    void Start() {

        _audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        _audioSource.pitch = startingPitch;
    }

    void Update() {

        if( _audioSource.pitch > 0 ) {
            _audioSource.pitch -= Time.deltaTime * startingPitch / decreaseAmount;
        }
    }
}
```

AudioSource.Pitch is used to change pitch of any audio source as you want...

Hope it helps... Happy Coding :)

Comment: but how it's connected to the propeller Spin script speed ? the idea or the goal is to change the pitch according to the propeller speed in the Spin script.

Comment: try replacing decreaseAmount with your rotation speed or change the multiplication and division order